# How to have a form 'POST' on each object i create

Tags: django

my questions is a little bit tricky, there  are a lot of web pages that i see and they have many things posted, for example a web page that offers information about places and restaurants in the city. so, all the places they post have an option to make a comment about this place. i know this can be done by a form with the method 'POST' but if i need to have a form POST for each one of these places, how can i do that?

i hope i have explained my self, to me it's a little bit tricky and i have thought about a solution but i couldn't have an answer. thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a form for each item in your list, then if you have 10 restaurants you should create one form for each restaurant. On each form you should include a `hidden` field containing the restaurant's id, and any other form control you need (comment, rating, submit button)